# Is there a way to use Telerik radgrid's export to excel on datatable in codebehind

Tags: asp.net, telerik, export-to-excel, radgrid

I am trying export a datatable to excel on an asp.net machine without office interop, since I'm using telerik for asp.net, is there a way to use the radgrid's export to excel function on a datatable in code behind at runtime without creating a design radgrid in the page?

Answer (score 1):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    RadGrid1 = new RadGrid();
    RadGrid1.ID = "RadGrid1";
    RadGrid1.NeedDataSource += new GridNeedDataSourceEventHandler(RadGrid1_NeedDataSource);

}

protected void RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Shipper", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("ShipperTemp", typeof(string));
    dt.Rows.Add("CShipper1", "1");
    dt.Rows.Add("BShipper2", "2");
    dt.Rows.Add("AShipper1", "1");
    dt.Rows.Add("EShipper1", "2");
    dt.Rows.Add("DShipper4", "4");

    (sender as RadGrid).DataSource = dt;

}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadGrid1.Rebind();
    Page.Controls.Add(RadGrid1); // It will not add control in your page
    RadGrid1.MasterTableView.ExportToExcel();
}
```